# Finding the Correct Serial Port

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port

I am creating a serial port monitor to monitor the data received in the serial port that my Arduino sends in. When Node.js finds the correct message sent in the serial, it will execute a terminal command. I have tested everything up to this point. However, I can't seem to find the correct port for the serial. This is my code and error message when the port is incorrect.

```
const { exec } = require('node:child_process')

var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var port = "141301";

var serialPort = new SerialPort(port, {
  baudRate: 9600
});

  serialPort.on("data", function(data) {
    if (data == '1') {
        exec('play horn.mp3')
    }
  });
```

Error Message:

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: Error: No such file or directory, cannot open 141301
Emitted 'error' event on SerialPort instance at:
    at SerialPort._error (/Users/***********/node_modules/@serialport/stream/lib/index.js:200:10)
    at /Users/***********/node_modules/@serialport/stream/lib/index.js:242:12

Node.js v18.16.0
```

I started with COM3 as the port, but failed. I tried COM2 and COM1, but the same error occurred. After looking in my port list, the Arduino was listed as `/dev/cu.usbmodem141301`. I tried 141301 as the port but still no.

Comment: If you plug in your device the correct COM port should be shown in the device manager.

Comment: I'm on Mac, so I don't have a device manager. `/dev/cu.usbmodem141301` is what shows in the Arduino device manager.